# Porque o onBlur não está sendo executado?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Estava querendo executar uma função no Javascript quando o *dropdown* perdesse o foco.

Estou fazendo dessa maneira, utilizando onBlur, e não está dando certo:

```js
function DesabilitaFiltro() {
   alert("ok");
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.DropDownList("Severidade", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Severidades, "Severidade", new { @class = "ui fluid search dropdown", style = "width: 100%", multiple = "", onchange = "Filtro()", onBlur="DesabilitaFiltro()" })
</div>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="Severidade" multiple="" name="Severidade" onBlur="DesabilitaFiltro()" onchange="Filtro()" style="width: 100%"><option value="">Severidade</option>
      <option>MEDIA</option>
      <option>ALTA</option>
      <option>BAIXA</option>
      <option>CRITICA</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Se alguém souber porque não está dando certo, me ajude...

Comment: Como fica o HTML disso?

Comment: ja tentou alterar o `onBlur` para `onblur`? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Comment: Ja pensou em usar outro evento? tipo um onclick no elemento da frente? Como o @CiganoMorrisonMendez disse ai, poste o html deste bicho ai para analisarmos melhor.

Comment: Postei o HTML...

Comment: Já tentei os dois jeitos @GuilhermeLautert.

Comment: Pq não roda no onchange?

Comment: @Italo aqui esta rodando de boa, apareceu o alert assim que o elemento perdeu o foco.

Answer (score 6):

Não existe nada errado com seu código. Pode ser apenas a ordem ou o momento que você está chamando o mesmo.

```html
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by randrade</title>
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body>
  

<div class="form-group">
   <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="Severidade" multiple="" name="Severidade" onblur="DesabilitaFiltro()" onchange="Filtro()" style="width: 100%"><option value="">Severidade</option>
      <option>MEDIA</option>
      <option>ALTA</option>
      <option>BAIXA</option>
      <option>CRITICA</option>
   </select>
</div>

<script>
function DesabilitaFiltro() {
   alert("ok");
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

Apenas um exemplo utilizando jQuery:

```html
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by randrade</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
  
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$("#Severidade").blur(function(){
    alert("OK");
});
});//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
   <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="Severidade" multiple="" name="Severidade" onchange="Filtro()" style="width: 100%"><option value="">Severidade</option>
      <option>MEDIA</option>
      <option>ALTA</option>
      <option>BAIXA</option>
      <option>CRITICA</option>
   </select>
</div>
  
</body></html>
```

Apenas verifique o momento que sua função está sendo "carregada" no navegador, isso pode estar ocasionando problemas.

[Fiddle - JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/qg07xcc1/)
[Fiddle - jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/b9sLkede/)

Comment: Por incrível que pareça no IE funciona, já no Firefox e Chrome não.

Comment: @Italo A minha resposta ou quando você adiciona em seu código?

Comment: Quando eu rodo o meu código @Randrade.

Comment: Isso é algo com o seu código. Aparece algum erro no console do navegador?

Comment: Parece não, e fui debbugando no F12 e não aparece nenhum erro.

Comment: @Italo Adicione a ordem de seus imports juntamente com o `@section Scripts{}`

Comment: coloquei section e não resolveu o problema.

Comment: @Italo adicione como está seu código na pergunta

Answer (score 4):

Seu código está funcionando sem problemas. Acredito que o comportamento que você esperar não é o que o método faz. Como sugestão, você pode rodar no onchange os dois metódos. Veja:

```js
function DesabilitaFiltro() {
  alert("ok");
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="Severidade" multiple="" name="Severidade" onchange="DesabilitaFiltro();Filtro();" style="width: 100%">
    <option value="">Severidade</option>
    <option>MEDIA</option>
    <option>ALTA</option>
    <option>BAIXA</option>
    <option>CRITICA</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Italo, sempre separe comportamento do HTML. 
Ao passo que você começar a fazer isso, verá que dúvidas no estilo "Porque XXXX não está executando" irão diminuir naturalmente.

No seu exemplo:

Inclua uma tag script no final do html e faça algo como:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#Severidade');
el.addEventListener('change', function alterouFiltro() {
  console.log('alterado');
}, false);

el.addEventListener('blur', function focoFiltro() {
  console.log('perdeu o foco');
}, false);
```

```html
<select id="Severidade">
  <option>Opção 1</option>
  <option>Opção 2</option>
  <option>Opção 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Eu colocaria dentro de uma $(document).ready(function ()?

Comment: Sim, também pode ser.